# Flutter won't load a particular image

Tags: image, flutter, flutter-web

When I try to load [this image](https://unsplash.com/photos/zuueig1w8WI) from Unsplash from local (located in `assets/images/`), nothing shows up and there is no error reported. When I change the image source to [network](https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553796661-17b7fa359f49?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTY0OTMzODA3NQ&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=1080), the image loads perfectly fine(but slower).
Does not work:

```dart
Container(
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
             image: AssetImage("assets/images/image.jpg"),
             fit: BoxFit.cover))
```

Works:

```dart
Container(
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
         image: DecorationImage(
             image: NetworkImage("https://source.unsplash.com/zuueig1w8WI/"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
```

### Currently using Flutter Web.

**Edit** Image is already in pubspec.

```yaml
name: website
description: Wesbite

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
version: 2.0.0+1

environment:
    sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
    flutter:
        sdk: flutter
    auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
    cached_network_image: ^2.5.0
    firebase_analytics: ^6.3.0
    font_awesome_flutter: ^8.11.0
    google_fonts: ^1.1.1
    http: ^0.12.2
    provider: ^4.3.2+3
    url_launcher: ^5.7.10
    velocity_x: ^1.3.1

dev_dependencies:
    flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
    assets:
        - assets/images/
        - assets/licenses/

    # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
    # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
    # the material Icons class.
    uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: may you also show the pubspec.yaml here? just want to know how you declare the asset on the config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the file extension in your assets folder.

The source image is .jfif which, although compatible, could mean flutter cannot find the file as its looking for image.jpg

Comment: The extension is .jpg. Flutter throws an error when it cannot find the image specified or cannot decode the image, but here I do not get any errors.

Comment: I have an indication of fix to the problem- the color profile of the image. The original color profile cannot be correctly interpreted by Flutter, but when converted to GIMP's color profile, the image loads using AssetImage.

Comment: I just spotted your are using flutter web. 
This could be a canvas kit issue. I've been having issues with canvaskit not displaying images properly but not throwing errors. I've had to switch to html canvas for now whilst they work on the issues, if converting the color profile has helped you I'll try and see if that's what CanvasKit is having issues with

Comment: Thank you for that. I am an Intermediate beginner with Flutter and don't know much about CanvasKit.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `pubspec.yaml` if you have included the asset path there. if you have not included the path then do the following.

[image]

**EDIT:** You don't have to add every single image path on 'pubspec.yaml', just add the main image path like:

> assets/images/

Comment: I already have the path in my pubspec. Other images are able to load fine.

Comment: Just try to save the image from photo editor software. maybe internally the image format is not .jpg